# How to interpret "которым больше семи веков"?

Tags: значения

> Как же здесь оказались книги, **которым больше семи веков**?

I'm a bit stumped with this part...

1) Why use the dative relative pronoun "которым" rather than the nominative?

2) I suppose "больше семи веков" means "more than seven centuries". Is "семи веков" in the genitive because "больше", just like "много", takes the genitive case?

Comment: You're correct about больше taking a genitive object.

Answer (score 6):

This is so called "dative of possession".

It's used for things like age, name, kinship etc. instead of possessive or genitive:

> *(возраст) мне семь лет*
>
> *имя мне легион*
>
> *я ему отец*
>
> *человек человеку волк*

and so on.

Note that this is a thing in Latin as well: *nomen mihi legio est, homo homini lupus est*, etc.

Answer (score 3):

All comparatives without `чем` govern genitive. `Пёс больше кота, толще кота, красивее кота. Автомобиль дороже велосипеда, тяжелее велосипеда, быстрее велосипеда.`

There is an expression about age with dative: `кому-то (или чему-то) столько-то лет (дней, месяцев, веков etc.)`  `Этим книгам больше семи веков` is an example of such expression.  Since `которым` replaces `этим книгам`, it should be in dative.

Answer (score 2):

1) This is a normal way to talk about ages in Russian:

*Ему*(dat.) *десять лет*. - He is ten years old.

There is (was) a kind of verb implied in this sentence which is used with dative noun:

*Ему [уже] исполнилось десять лет.*

2) Yes, *больше* takes genitive (if it is in the same clause). You may say either

*Десять больше пяти*(gen.).

or

*Десять больше, чем пять*(nom.).